# How to join one table two times, but get different column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Question:**

How can I join one table two times (in this case `sl_jednostka_miary`), but get different column names without specifying every column?
I could just call every column, but there is too many of them.

EDIT: I can call every column by name from `sl_jednostka_miary`, but I don't want to call columns from other tables.

**What I tried:**

```
SELECT *, j_porownawcza.jm_id AS jp_id, j_porownawcza.jm_kod AS jp_kod, j_porownawcza.jm_opis AS jp_opis
FROM tw__towar
        INNER JOIN sl_typ_towaru ON tt_id = tw_ttid
        INNER JOIN sl_jednostka_miary ON jm_id = tw_jmid
        INNER JOIN sl_jednostka_miary AS j_porownawcza ON j_porownawcza.jm_id = tw_jpid
```

**Problem:**

I've tried query above, but the problem is that I get this table shown three times - two times with the same column names, and one time with new column names.

Comment: Replace `*` with list of fields. ;) I also suggest to read this: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: *I could just call every column, but there is too many of them."* That is **exactly** what you need to do.

Comment: If you want your query to output different column names, but don't want to specify each column by hand, I don't think there's a solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify an alias for each table and use [alias_name].* from list of all columns of each table.

Thy this:

```
Select W.*, S.* , t1.* 
-- Must list field name for only one table 
, t2.Col1 as t2_Col1, t2.Col2 as t2_Col2 , t2.Col3 as t2_Col3 ,....
FROM tw__towar AS W
        INNER JOIN sl_typ_towaru AS S  ON S.tt_id = W.tw_ttid
        INNER JOIN sl_jednostka_miary AS t1 ON t1.jm_id = W.tw_jmid
        INNER JOIN sl_jednostka_miary AS t2 ON t2.jm_id = W.tw_jpid
```

Comment: Aside: The table alias isn't required for all tables, e.g. instead of `W.*` you could use `tw_towar.*`. As you have explained, the problem is the table that appears twice in the joins where the table name is not sufficient to distinguish between the instances.